How can I stop this GBA emulator from showing corrupted pixels
I've been working on this GBA emulator project for sometime now, and I got an SDL window to show and for pixels to translate and become colorized but for whatever reason when I try to run the program it just shows a corrupted screen with random colored pixels all over the place, similar to when certain TV's are broken. It's like TV Static but colored. Any help or suggestions? Sorry for the long code btw, I'm just not sure where the issue lies. Also, I've been trying it out with a rom of Pokemon Firered, so not sure if that's where the issue lies but I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks!
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <filesystem>

// Define GBA screen dimensions
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 240;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 160;
const int TILE_SIZE = 8;
const int TILE_BYTES = 32;  // Each tile is 8x8 pixels, 4 bits per pixel (32 bytes)

// Debug flag
const bool DEBUG = true;

// Memory Class
class Memory {
public:
    std::vector<uint8_t> rom;
    std::vector<uint8_t> ram;
    std::vector<uint32_t> framebuffer;
    std::vector<uint32_t> palette;
    uint32_t tile_base_address;

    Memory() : ram(0x40000), framebuffer(SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0xFFFFFFFF), tile_base_address(0) {}

    void load_rom(const std::string &rom_path) {
        std::ifstream rom_file(rom_path, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
        if (!rom_file.is_open()) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to open ROM file");
        }

        std::streamsize rom_size = rom_file.tellg();
        rom_file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

        rom.resize(rom_size);
        if (!rom_file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(rom.data()), rom_size)) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to read ROM file");
        }
        if (DEBUG) {
            std::cout << "ROM loaded successfully. Size: " << rom_size << " bytes" << std::endl;
        }

        tile_base_address = find_tile_base_address();
        if (DEBUG) {
            std::cout << "Tile base address identified at: 0x" << std::hex << tile_base_address << std::dec << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void write_to_framebuffer(int x, int y, uint32_t color) {
        if (x >= 0 && x < SCREEN_WIDTH && y >= 0 && y < SCREEN_HEIGHT) {
            framebuffer[y * SCREEN_WIDTH + x] = color;
        }
    }

    void load_palette() {
        palette.resize(256);
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
            uint16_t color = rom[0x300 + i * 2] | (rom[0x300 + i * 2 + 1] << 8);
            palette[i] = gba_color_to_sdl_color(color);
            if (DEBUG) {
                std::cout << "Palette color " << i << ": " << std::hex << palette[i] << std::dec << std::endl;
            }
        }
        if (DEBUG) {
            std::cout << "Palette loaded successfully." << std::endl;
        }
    }

    uint32_t gba_color_to_sdl_color(uint16_t gba_color) {
        uint32_t r = (gba_color & 0x1F) << 3;
        uint32_t g = ((gba_color >> 5) & 0x1F) << 3;
        uint32_t b = ((gba_color >> 10) & 0x1F) << 3;
        uint32_t color = (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
        if (DEBUG) {
            std::cout << "GBA Color: " << std::hex << gba_color << " -> SDL Color: " << color << std::dec << std::endl;
        }
        return color;
    }

    bool is_tile_data(const uint8_t *data, size_t size) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            if (data[i] > 15) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    uint32_t find_tile_base_address() {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < rom.size() - TILE_BYTES; ++i) {
            if (is_tile_data(&rom[i], TILE_BYTES)) {
                return static_cast<uint32_t>(i);
            }
        }
        throw std::runtime_error("Tile base address not found in ROM");
    }

    void render_tiles() {
        if (DEBUG) {
            std::cout << "Rendering tiles..." << std::endl;
        }
        for (int ty = 0; ty < SCREEN_HEIGHT; ty += TILE_SIZE) {
            for (int tx = 0; tx < SCREEN_WIDTH; tx += TILE_SIZE) {
                for (int y = 0; y < TILE_SIZE; ++y) {
                    for (int x = 0; x < TILE_SIZE; x += 2) {
                        int tile_index = tile_base_address + ((ty / TILE_SIZE) * (SCREEN_WIDTH / TILE_SIZE) + (tx / TILE_SIZE)) * TILE_BYTES + y * 4 + x / 2;
                        if (tile_index >= rom.size()) {
                            if (DEBUG) {
                                std::cout << "Tile index out of range: " << tile_index << std::endl;
                            }
                            continue;
                        }
                        uint8_t byte = rom[tile_index];
                        uint8_t pixel1 = byte & 0xF;
                        uint8_t pixel2 = (byte >> 4) & 0xF;
                        if (pixel1 >= palette.size() || pixel2 >= palette.size()) {
                            if (DEBUG) {
                                std::cout << "Invalid pixel value at tile_index: " << tile_index << std::endl;
                            }
                            continue;
                        }
                        uint32_t color1 = palette[pixel1];
                        uint32_t color2 = palette[pixel2];
                        write_to_framebuffer(tx + x, ty + y, color1);
                        write_to_framebuffer(tx + x + 1, ty + y, color2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (DEBUG) {
            std::cout << "Tiles rendered." << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

// SDL Handler
void initialize_SDL(SDL_Window *&window, SDL_Renderer *&renderer) {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to initialize SDL: " + std::string(SDL_GetError()));
    }

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("GBA Emulator",
                              SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                              SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                              SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT,
                              SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    if (window == nullptr) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create window: " + std::string(SDL_GetError()));
    }

    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    if (renderer == nullptr) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create renderer: " + std::string(SDL_GetError()));
    }
    if (DEBUG) {
        std::cout << "SDL initialized successfully." << std::endl;
    }
}

void cleanup_SDL(SDL_Window *window, SDL_Renderer *renderer) {
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    if (DEBUG) {
        std::cout << "SDL cleaned up." << std::endl;
    }
}

void render_framebuffer(SDL_Renderer *renderer, const std::vector<uint32_t> &framebuffer) {
    SDL_Texture *texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    if (texture == nullptr) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create texture: " + std::string(SDL_GetError()));
    }
    SDL_UpdateTexture(texture, nullptr, framebuffer.data(), SCREEN_WIDTH * sizeof(uint32_t));
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, nullptr, nullptr);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
    if (DEBUG) {
        std::cout << "Framebuffer rendered." << std::endl;
    }
}

std::string find_rom_file() {
    for (const auto &entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(".")) {
        if (entry.path().extension() == ".gba") {
            return entry.path().string();
        }
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("No ROM file found in the current directory");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    try {
        if (DEBUG) {
            std::cout << "Initializing memory..." << std::endl;
        }
        Memory memory;

        std::string rom_path;
        if (argc >= 2) {
            rom_path = argv[1];
        } else {
            rom_path = find_rom_file();
        }
        if (DEBUG) {
            std::cout << "ROM path: " << rom_path << std::endl;
        }
        memory.load_rom(rom_path);

        SDL_Window *window = nullptr;
        SDL_Renderer *renderer = nullptr;
        if (DEBUG) {
            std::cout << "Initializing SDL..." << std::endl;
        }
        initialize_SDL(window, renderer);

        if (DEBUG) {
            std::cout << "Loading palette..." << std::endl;
        }
        memory.load_palette();

        memory.render_tiles();  // Make sure to render the tiles once after loading the palette

        bool quit = false;
        SDL_Event e;

        while (!quit) {
            while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0) {
                if (e.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                    quit = true;
                }
            }

            render_framebuffer(renderer, memory.framebuffer);
            SDL_Delay(16);  // Approximately 60 FPS
        }

        cleanup_SDL(window, renderer);
    } catch (const std::exception &e) {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}



I'm not so sure about the expression r << 16... Because r is an 8-bit type, you can't shift it 16 bits. Even after integer promotion, the result will then be converted back to an uint8_t IIRC, and you will loose the bits. Why not use uint32_t for the r, g and b variables?

@Someprogrammerdude I agree to make r,g,b uint32_t. uint8_t overflow might be enough undefined behaviour that all bets are off. But I am a bit surprised that he doesn't end up with a correct blue channel and zeroes for red/green if that was the root cause. There may be something else going wrong in addition.

I did implement your advice @Someprogrammerdude but unfortunately it still looks corrupted. I updated my code above accordingly.

@MartinBrown Overflow shouldn't be a problem here. According to cppreference, for built-in bitwise shift operators: "Integral promotions are performed on both operands." And regarding Integral promotion: "In particular, arithmetic operators do not accept types smaller than int as arguments, and integral promotions are automatically applied after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, if applicable."

@Someprogrammerdude The result will not be "converted back" to 8-bit. Quoting from expr.shift: "The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand."

Interesting @heapunderrun... what do you recommend I do? Thanks!

I don't know anything about GBA; just some general thoughts… The line uint16_t color = rom[0x300 + i * 2] | (rom[0x300 + i * 2 + 1] << 8); – This will cause out-of-bounds access if the rom vector contains less than 1280 bytes. Maybe add a minimum size check after loading the ROM from a file? And what magic constant is 0x300 here? Also, are you sure your find_tile_base_address() function finds the correct address? Maybe the first occurrence of 32 bytes simply with all their values lower than 0x10 is not a sufficient indicator?

One thought is that one of the classic BMP file formats is 16 bit in the same way as your source data and I think in the same order. It might be worth saving the ROMs as a file and then mocking up a bitmap header to look at them in an image editor. Or create a DIB in memory and  display it (but that opens another can of worms). Looking at the ROM contents in a debugger of hex editor might be helpful too.

@heapunderrun my default assumption with C compilers and unsigned arithmetic or shifts on anything smaller than an int is that they are out to get you. More an issue on embedded systems where it isn't standards compliant (due to hardware limitations).
